# Parallel deletion of GKE nodes

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I am trying to run a job on GKE for 5 mins and 50 nodes. However when i scale down instances it happens sequentially and thus costing me much more for a 4-5 min job.

Is there any way to paralelly delete GKE instances?

Comment: It can be risky to drain multiple nodes simultaneously, because you typically build a service to be high-available by distributing its pods across nodes and use anti-affinity. That design makes service resilient to 1-node failures. But if you do parallel drainage, all nodes running pods for that service could go down simultaneously, and now the service is temporarily dead. If you can accept downtime, that's ok. Ex you've replicated your app in a 2nd region, then region 1 down means a bit slower app response in that region as traffic routes to region 2. Or design so that service can be down.

Answer (score 1):

Kubernetes cluster has an underlying Instance Group.

I was able to delete the nodes in parallel by directly changing the number of nodes in Instance Group from 50 to 5.

All nodes were deleted within 30 seconds and GKE had also automatically updated the cluster size with the new value.

Comment: I understand this might work in your implementation, but is **unsafe**! Basically correspond so switch off the machine without letting kubernetes know that this is happening. You should not even use the classical autoscaler of the instance Group "Do not use Compute Engine autoscaling with managed instance groups that are owned by Google Kubernetes Engine. For Google Kubernetes Engine groups, use Cluster Autoscaling instead." As you can see it is not the Best 
 Practise https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/resizing-a-container-cluster

Comment: This was a huge help to me. Thanks! The gcloud containers resize command was prohibitively slow.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [already](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/resizing-a-container-cluster) to scale down your cluster:

```
$ gcloud container clusters resize [CLUSTER_NAME] --node-pool [NODE_POOL] --size [SIZE]
```

I believe there are other option to speed up this process.
On other other hand if you are reeling on autoscaler you could try if with that command the resize is faster and you would be able to meet your requirements. However keep in mind that the purpose of Kubernetes is not create an infrastructure were it is extremely fast to spin up and add 50 nodes and when you are done to kill them.

Consider also from the [doumentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/safely-drain-node/#use-kubectl-drain-to-remove-a-node-from-service):

> The kubectl drain command should only be issued to a single node at a time. However, you can run multiple kubectl drain commands for different node in parallel, in different terminals or in the background. Multiple drain commands running concurrently will still respect the PodDisruptionBudget you specify.

Therefore it turns out from the documentation that drain a node (that is an essential phase to remove a node) it is discouraged

Comment: Nothing wrong with drainage, but there are risks when done in parallel, depending on your infrastructure architecture. See my comment to OP.